# why when creating new java class, customization wizard doesn't display?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class, createfile

this is the dialog tab that display
[image: this is the dialog tab that display]
when creating a new java class it asks me to enter class name only and doesn't show this dialog.

this is the dialog tab I want to display when creating new java class
[image: this is the dialog tab I want to display when creating new java class]

Comment: Maybe just different versions of IDE make this difference They are almost the same. You can enter the name, and chose the type, the package is where you right-click at, the superclass can be pointed out with `extends xxx` in the java file.

Comment: i knew that but i was asking if i can get that wizard back                                                        thanks :)